# Can I get a mortgage from a foreign bank?

Tags: mortgage, united-kingdom, banking

I live in the UK is it possible to transfer a mortgage to a bank based in a different country that doesn't operate in the UK, say Germany or United states for example?

Comment: Probably not, but may I enquire as to why you want to do this?

Comment: You definitely can, I don't understand why everyone thinks you can't. Two reasons : lower interest rates; you think a currency will lose value (us dollar anyone).

Answer (score 5):

Most likely **NO**

If you are talking about a mortgage for a *property* (house or land), it is highly unlikely as the main security against your mortgage is the property and an oversea bank would have a hard time repossessing the property in case of default.

I have economic activity and assets both in France and the UK and I can categorically answer for the case of French bank, they will not offer money against an asset they cannot put their hands on. I strongly suspect the same for German and US banks.

Other answers mention foreign banks offering mortgage in the UK but they were doing that through a UK branch, not from their country of origin.

---

The one thing which is possible (I almost did it but then backed out).

A bank in France (or any country for that matter) was perfectly ok to give me a secured loan (=mortgage).

- If the collateral was a house in the country (France), no problem.
- If the collateral was a house in another country (the UK in my example), no deal!
  Except, since I had assets in France (some very long term saving account, akin to what you'd use for a pension, but not blocked until retirement age either), the bank was ready to give me a sizeable loan, interest only, as long as I could prove that my income could pay the interests and my savings could repay the principal at the term of the mortgage.
  In these conditions, they did not care what I would do with the loan money (like buying a house in another country) because they would have had a lien on my savings so the risk of default was low enough for them.

So baseline, if you want to borrow large sum of money from any bank, you have to offer them a collateral that they feel safe enough with. A property *in another country* is usually **not** safe enough for them.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer YES you can, there are loads here are some links :
[world first](http://www.worldfirst.com/?ID=780&gclid=CJ252ZnRnaQCFY1k4wodlEjlEw#tab=videos) , [Baydon Hill](http://www.baydonhillfx.com/mortgages) , [IPF](http://www.internationalprivatefinance.com/?gclid=CMeSy5vRnaQCFUH92AodAji1Dw)

Just googling "foreign currency mortgage", "international mortgage", or "overseas mortgage" gets you loads of starting points.  I believe its an established and well used process, and they would be "classified" as a "normal" mortgage.

The process even has its own wiki [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_currency_mortgage)

Incidentally I considered doing it myself. I looked into it briefly, but the cost of fee's seemed to outweigh the **possible** future benefits of lower interest rates and currency fluctuations.

Comment: The links you have given are more from a resident in country buying property abroad. IE a resident of US buying a property in Dubai/UK etc. The question is being a resident in US and holding a US property would a foreign bank give you a mortgage loan. For a loan to be treated as Mortage in the resident country the normal rule apply that the financial institution be resident of the country. This is where the tax / legal provisions apply. A foreign institution can still lead, but they would not be treated as mortgage in resident country for the purpose of taxation and legal.

Comment: I don't understand your point. It is a widely used practice, I imagine the links I listed highlight buying abroad, as that is the reason most people do it.  "For a loan to be treated as Mortage in the resident country" well surely its not the resident country, it is the country the bank is registered in.  Just to repeat, it is common practice to buy a house in your resident country with a mortgage from a bank registered in foreign county, and it is easy to do. I fail to see why you think it isn't.

Comment: So if I am in US and buy a property in US, the loan is from a Bank in UK that has no presence in US. Would I get a tax benefit similar to the one I get if I take a mortgage loan from a bank in US?

Comment: I have no idea what the tax benefits in the US are ? What are they ?

Comment: The first link is dead, the second points to some kind of forex scam, the third is somewhat relevant but does describe a company that offers mortgages in very specific locations in Europe, likely where they have enough presence to be able to handle a foreclosure process. I doubt that can be treated as a generic "yes" justification.

Comment: @littleadv appreciate the critique of my 13yr old answer to a question.

Answer (score -1):

You definitely used to be able to (see [this BBC article from 2006](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/programmes/moneybox/6051276.stm)), and I would imagine that you still can, although I also imagine that it would be more difficult than it used to be, as with all mortgages.

**EDIT:** And [here's](http://www.moneyhospital.co.uk/blog/post/fancy-a-Chinese-mortgage-20157) an article from last year about Chinese banks targeting the UK mortgage market.

Comment: I think those are all examples of foreign banks which are operating in the UK. Also the loans suggested in those links are all denominated in sterling.